# Zero of a polynomial and factors

Tags: polynomials

If $(a-b)$ and $(a+b)$ are the zeroes of the polynomial $f(x)=2x^3-6x^2+5x-7$ find the value of $a$ and $b$. I solved this problem considering ${x-(a-b)}   , {x-(a+b)}$  but I could not evaluate the values of a and b

Comment: The function $f(x)=2x^3-6x^2+5x-7$ has only one real root.

Comment: Do $a,b$ have to be real numbers and non zero? If so they do not exist. $f(x)$ has one real root (and it's messy) and two complex conjugate roots.

Comment: Is the problem wrong?